# Fingerprint Reader Lenovo Thinkpad L13 - Synaptics Driver

Tags: drivers, lenovo, thinkpad, fingerprint-reader

I read some of the questions here about the fingerprint reader support.
Here I am asking spcecifically for the **Lenovo Thinkpad L13**.

I am using Ubuntu 19.10 but I think it would be the same for other versions.

lsusb shows `ID 06cb:00be Synaptics Inc.`

I installed libpam-fprintd fprint-demo and libfprint0

fprint-demo says *No devices found*.

Is there any driver for this Synaptic device available?

Or how can I use the fingerprint sensor with Ubuntu

Comment: Lenovo, like most many other manufacturers, will use multiple different kinds of peripherals when building systems. Not all machines of the same model will have the same fingerprint reader. This makes life difficult for Ubuntu users. Thank you for posting the detail you found!

Answer (score 2):

For now, it's really tricky.

19.10 uses outdated `fwmgr` and `fprintd`. You'll need at least `fwmgr-1.3.5` and `fprintd-1.90`. They are available in next Ubuntu release - `focus` which is on early stage of development.

You can get up-to-date version of `fwupd` package from `snap`, but you should build `fprintd-1.90` packages from source.

Also, fingerprint reader firmware should be updated, but this is tricky as well, because firmware you need is marked as `testing` and current version of `fwupd` fails to download it.

All in all, I spent all evenings this week tinkering and finally managed to get it working.
I would suggest to wait for Ubuntu `focus` where fingerprint will be working out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, I was loosing hope. As the beta is planned to come out in a little more than a week and the final release on April 23rd, I am happy to wait.

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 20.04 focal fossa but `fprintd-enroll` gives me `list_devices failed: No devices available`. Any idea why?

Comment: Unfortionately the driver for the 06cb:00be Synaptics device seems not to be included in Focal Fossa. fprintd-1.90 shows "no devicees available".

Comment: You need to enable `testing` remote in `fwupdmgr`.
See here how: https://github.com/fwupd/fwupd/wiki/LVFS-Testing-remote

Firmware you need to to install is listed here: https://fwupd.org/lvfs/search?value=prometheus

Comment: It didn't work for me. The firmware from the link is for 00bd only according to the contained XML file, not 00be.

Comment: @zeroinfinity can you please add your last comment to your answer? It works for me (Lenovo X1 Carbon) and is quite hidden here in the comments ...

Answer (score 0):

Support for this device has been added: Synaptics 06cb:00be through the development of a libfprint compatible library.

1. Install this package: https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90/files/9106908/libfprint-tod-git.tar.gz
2. Clone this git: https://github.com/Popax21/synaTudor
3. Follow the instructions.

If you need any help, please contact me back.

Comment: I am sorry .. this might be a silly question.. but how to install libfprint-tod-git.tar.gz?

Comment: @RizwanKhan Execute in arch: makepkg -si PKGBUILD